# How to use ecs service dicovery

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, fargate

I'm trying to use amazon service discovery to register a Redis server in order to be reachable by other **ECS** services in the same cluster.

I'm using **EC2** to deploy my services not Fargate, so service discovery create a simple **SRV** DNS record, that's mean my others services must request **R53** service to get a real "**A**" record to have access to Redis service.

My question for DevOps/AWS engineer is: what's the correct way to do so? A request to **R53** each time absolutely not a good idea.

My solution is in comments.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?

Comment: Could you post an answer? Then people can upvote it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to answer but as the question was marked as closed it wasn't possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal can be achieved via several solutions. We can use service with **awsvpc** as network mode, so your service can get a real "**A**" **DNS** record and ENI interface, you must pay attention with this solution, ec2 instances has a limited number of ENI that can be attached, for a micro or small I think max 3.

Other solution more flexible is to use an internal **NLB** or custom proxy like **HAproxy** as **ambassador**, you run the proxy as service with awsvpc so he can get his "**A**" **DNS** record eg **proxy.prod**, all other services like Redis, Mongo, Elasticsearch ... can be configured as service with bridge networking mode so they will get an **SRV** record if configured with service discovery.

Finally you have to configure your proxy to redirect all traffic to desired service using port forwarding. **HAproxy** can resolve "**SRV**" records so you don't have to deal with that **HAproxy** will do it for you, you must just configure your app to use **proxy.prod** + port, for each service so:

- *Redis* **proxy.prod:6379**
- *Mongo* **proxy.prod:27017**
- And so on...

Using this technique you can do a lot of amazing things, no matter where your proxy can lives, it can run as container in the same node with your apps or on a **Fargate** or in another node ...